# Searching in list view which loaded from database in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have database in my application which is completely loading in listview but when doing searching in listview its not working and the app is not crashing bellow is my code in which i retrieve data from database and loding in listview .

```
    -------------DatabaseClass----
public Cursor getCursor() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    // queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
    // openDataBase();

    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        String[] asColumnsToReturn = new String[] { "lang_from","_id" };
        c = myDataBase.query("words2", asColumnsToReturn, null, null, null,
                null, null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("" + e);
    }
    return c;
}

     -----------MainActivity----------------
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

DatabaseClass myDbHelper;
private Cursor ourCursor = null;
private IngredientAdapter adapter = null;

ListView myListView;
EditText etSearch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etsearch);
    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    myListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    // = new DatabaseClass();
    myDbHelper = new DatabaseClass(this);

    try {

        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }

    try {

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        ourCursor = myDbHelper.getCursor();
        startManagingCursor(ourCursor);
        try {
            adapter = new IngredientAdapter(this, ourCursor);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("" + e);
        }
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {

        throw sqle;

    }
    etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            // MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            Log.d("TAGGGGGGGG", cs.toString());
            adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

            // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

        }
    });
}

class IngredientAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public IngredientAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        IngredientHolder holder = (IngredientHolder) row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(c, myDbHelper);
        Log.d("TAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGGGGG", "GOOD");
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        IngredientHolder holder = new IngredientHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        Log.d("TAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGGGGG", "GOOD");
        return (row);
    }
}

class IngredientHolder {
    private TextView name = null;

    IngredientHolder(View row) {
        name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.ingredientText);

    }

    void populateFrom(Cursor c, DatabaseClass r) {
        name.setText(r.getName(c));
    }
}
 }
```

Please help and sorry for weak english

Answer (score 2):

I've Implemented this kind of feature in my application.

A brief explanation. 
Implement your own class that extends Filter, like the next class:

```
private class PlanetFilter extends Filter {
@Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        // We implement here the filter logic
        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            // No filter implemented we return all the list
            results.values = planetList;
            results.count = planetList.size();
        }
        else {
            // We perform filtering operation
            List<Planet> nPlanetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();

            for (Planet p : planetList) {
                if (p.getName().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                    nPlanetList.add(p);
            }

            results.values = nPlanetList;
            results.count = nPlanetList.size();

        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

In your base adapter implements Filterable interface and it has to implement getFilter() method:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (planetFilter == null)
        planetFilter = new PlanetFilter();

    return planetFilter;
}
```

And to tie all together, use `textWatcher` on your `edittext`, where you enter the text.

```
editTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        System.out.println("Text ["+s+"]");
        aAdpt.getFilter().filter(s.toString());                           
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

**That code is taken from the next [tutorial](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html).**

Comment: ok i will try you code but can u tell me what exact problem in my code and what change is require for it plz i am talking about my code

Comment: @hope You need to elaborate more, if you want people try to help you. What is exactly "but when doing searching in listview it not working", do you get results at all or not. The app is crashing or not.

Answer (score 0):

You never specify a filter for your adapter - you need to declare such and tell it based on what exactly to filter.

Comment: @hope here is the first answer i found regarding filters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android. It will show you the general idea, though I do not advise declaring the filter as inner class