# EditText to filter items in listview. How to?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, filter, android-edittext

I've got a listview that shows the applications installed in my device. I want create a editText that filter the items i search. I've already create the edittext but doesn't work and nothing appear when i type to search something. This is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemLongClickListener{
    private PackageManager packageManager = null;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
    private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;
    EditText inputSearch;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 

        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        new LoadApplications().execute();

        /** refresh btn*/
        Button bottone1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bottone1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new LoadApplications().execute();

            }   
        });
        /** EditText filter */
        // Edit text
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTxt);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // Filter when someone type in the edittext
                MainActivity.this.listadaptor.getFilter().filter(cs);   
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });
    };



    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try {
                if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                    applist.add(info);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return applist;
    }


    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {        

        public ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.snippet_list_row, applist);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        protected void onDestroy() {
            if(progress!=null)
                if(progress.isShowing()){
                progress.dismiss();
                }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            setListAdapter(listadaptor);
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null,
                    "Loading...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

And the Adapter EDITED:

```
    public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo>  { 
    private List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = null; 
    private Context context; 
    private PackageManager packageManager; 

    public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, 
            List<ApplicationInfo> appsList) { 
        super(context, textViewResourceId, appsList); 
        this.context = context; 
        this.appsList = appsList; 
        packageManager = context.getPackageManager(); 
    } 

    @Override
    public int getCount() { 
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.size() : 0); 
    } 

    @Override
    public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) { 
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.get(position) : null); 
    } 

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) { 
        return position; 
    } 

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
        View view = convertView; 
        if (null == view) { 
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context 
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_list_row, null); 
        } 



        ApplicationInfo data = appsList.get(position); 
        if (null != data) { 
            TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name); 
            TextView packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_paackage); 
            ImageView iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon); 

            appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager)); 
            packageName.setText(data.packageName); 
            iconview.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager)); 
        } 
        return view; 
    } 

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                appsList = (List<ApplicationInfo>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                ArrayList<String> FilteredArrayNames = new ArrayList<String>();

                // perform your search here using the searchConstraint String.



                    results.count = FilteredArrayNames.size();
                    results.values = FilteredArrayNames;



                return results;
            }
        };

        return filter;
    }
};
```

Someone can help me? Actually when i type to search nothing change and rest the whole listview. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a SearchView instead ? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html

Comment: With edittext i can extend the filter with all android version.. searchview not.. i think.

Comment: SearchView is indeed only available as from API 11. There are options to be explored for compatibility (http://developer.android.com/training/search/backward-compat.html) but it might not suit your needs ... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

**I changed the adapter class**

```
public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo>  { 
    private List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = null; 
    private Context context; 
    private PackageManager packageManager;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> listOfApp;

    public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, 
            List<ApplicationInfo> appsList) { 
        super(context, textViewResourceId, appsList); 
        this.context = context; 
        this.appsList = appsList;
        this.listOfApp = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>(); //Added here
        packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        listOfApp.addAll(appsList);
    } 

    @Override
    public int getCount() { 
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.size() : 0); 
    } 

    @Override
    public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) { 
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.get(position) : null); 
    } 

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) { 
        return position; 
    } 

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
        View view = convertView; 
        if (null == view) { 
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context 
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_list_row, null); 
        } 

        ApplicationInfo data = appsList.get(position); 
        if (null != data) { 
            TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name); 
            TextView packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_paackage); 
            ImageView iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon); 

            appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager)); 
            packageName.setText(data.packageName); 
            iconview.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager)); 
        } 
        return view; 
    } 

 // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        appsList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            appsList.addAll(listOfApp);
        } 
        else
        {
            for (ApplicationInfo ai : listOfApp) 
            {
                if (ai.loadLabel(packageManager).toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) 
                {
                    appsList.add(ai);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

**and change in Activity**

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
               // I changed here to call filter method from Adapter class.
               String text =inputSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                listadaptor.filter(text);
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: crash when i open the app: at com.dd.application.ApplicationAdapter.<init>(ApplicationAdapter.java:31)

Comment: @David_D i edited Adapter class. I added this.listOfApp = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>(); Now try again.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `Filterable` interface and implement it  in your Adapter class.
Define the `getFilter()` method of the interface which will return the filtered list items in the adapter. Take a look at the following question:

[List View Filter Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android)

OR use [SearchView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html)

Comment: I don't know if i ask too much, but, can you try to edit my adapter and add the part that you think needs? because really it's about 2 weeks i try without results :(

Comment: you just need to define a getFIlter() method which returns the filtered items based on the query you entered in the EditText. Just go through the code on the link i shared.. It is very simple

Comment: write the logic of filtering in the performFiltering() method and then create a new list and return it.. then it automatically sets the new list in the adapter.

Comment: It's very first time i use this type of control sorry..so i can't only write what i've already done right?

Comment: What you are doing is just creating an empty FilterResults object.. you have to add your filtered list in that object them return it. That is why your listview becomes empty