# How to filter ListView set by class with EditText?

Tags: java, android, class, listview, android-edittext

I have a ListView that populates with items from `ArrayList<myClass>`. I have a layout and custom adapter and they show up just fine. `myClass` has two `textview`s in. I am wondering how I can filter out results by checking if what a user types in the edittext matches either of the `textview`s in the `myClass` class. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android) solution, but it failed because I am using classes to fill my `listview`, not strings. Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for [SearchView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html).  It's got some useful capabilities.  All you need to do is add on a [OnQueryTextListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html) and you'll be well on your way to manipulating a ListView.

Comment: Thanks for steering me in the right directio. Almost finished implementing it.