# How to make searching faster from ArrayList?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, full-text-search

I have an ArrayList which has over 15000 Strings which is a line and I am displaying the results with their search words which are displayed using ArrayAdapter but it takes about 6-8 sec to search through the whole ArrayList. Is it possible to make it quicker or at least view the results that are already found and keep the searching continue at the background. Below is the link where I posted the question in detail. I really need help on this any help would be appreciated.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150994/android-how-to-make-searching-initials-of-the-words-from-a-line-in-textfile-fas

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a filterable listview for searching, look this example: [List View Filter Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android)  
[There](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#Loops) are many tips to improve search performance. 
And you should wrap your data into a model instead of many strings then override `equal` method for compare two object for searching.

Answer (score 0):

Hi given the use case I under stood that you are searching for the content from a file 
 which is containing 15,000 lines when user types in the text box. ArrayList is the
 efficient data structure to use for search purposes. so the only solution is to divide the
 file in to smaller  chunks and base on the input read from the expected file and display
 the content.

for example:

Pseudo code:
 if user types for initials stars with a search in one file
 else if  user types for initials stars with b search in one file
 ........................................
 ........................................
 based on use case

---

else

---

default file

---

try in this way check whether performance improves