# [Android]How to do a search on the first name and last name only?

Tags: java, android

This is my main activity .java

```
  package com.example.search;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public User getUserByName(String firstName, String lastName) {
    synchronized (userList) {
        Iterator<User> iterator = userList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            User user = (User) iterator.next();
            if (user.getFirstName().equals(firstName)
                    && user.getLastName().equals(lastName)) {
                return user;
            }
        }
        // no user found
        return null;
    }
}


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private EditText firstNameEditText;
    private EditText lastNameEditText;
    private UserListAdapter<User> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        firstNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstNameEditText);
        lastNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastNameEditText);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayList<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();
        // add items to list
        adapter = new UserListAdapter<User>(this,
                R.layout.textview_layout, usersList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        firstNameEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus) {
                    adapter.setFilterMode(UserListAdapter.MODE_FILTER_BY_FIRST_NAME);
                }
            }
        });
        lastNameEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus) {
                    adapter.setFilterMode(UserListAdapter.MODE_FILTER_BY_LAST_NAME);
                }
            }
        });
        TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
        };

        firstNameEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        lastNameEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    }

    public static class UserListAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
        public static final int MODE_FILTER_BY_FIRST_NAME = 0xFEED;
        public static final int MODE_FILTER_BY_LAST_NAME = 0xDEAF;
        private List<T> objects;
        private int filterMode;

        public UserListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<T> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            init(objects);
        }

        public UserListAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                int textViewResourceId, T[] objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
            init(Arrays.asList(objects));
        }

        private void init(List<T> objects) {
            this.objects = objects;
        }

        public UserListAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
            init(objects);
        }

        public UserListAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
        }

        public UserListAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
            super(context, resource);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return new Filter() {

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                        FilterResults results) {
                    UserListAdapter.this.clear();
                    ArrayList<T> list = (ArrayList<T>) results.values;
                    UserListAdapter.this.addAll(list);
                    if (results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected synchronized FilterResults performFiltering(
                        CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
                    Iterator<T> iterator = objects.iterator();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        T t = (T) iterator.next();
                        User user = (User) t;
                        String s = null;
                        if (filterMode == MODE_FILTER_BY_FIRST_NAME) {
                            s = user.getFirstName();
                        } else if (filterMode == MODE_FILTER_BY_LAST_NAME) {
                            s = user.getLastName();
                        }
                        if (s.equals(constraint.toString())) {
                            list.add(t);
                        }
                    }
                    results.values = list;
                    results.count = list.size();
                    return results;
                }
            };
        }

        public int getFilterMode() {
            return filterMode;
        }

        public void setFilterMode(int filterMode) {
            this.filterMode = filterMode;
        }
    }

    public static class User {
        // attributes
        private String accountID;
        private String companyName;
        private String designation;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String profileimageBLOB;

        // behaviors
        public User() // default constructor
        {
            // attributes will be initialized to their default values
        }

        public User(String accID, String comName, String design, String fName,
                String lName, String image) // parameterized constructor
        {
            accountID = accID;
            companyName = comName;
            designation = design;
            firstName = fName;
            lastName = lName;
            profileimageBLOB = image;
        }

        // set and get methods
        public void setAccountID(String accID) {
            accountID = accID;
        }

        public String getAccountID() {
            return accountID;
        }

        public void setCompanyName(String comName) {
            companyName = comName;
        }

        public String getCompanyName() {
            return companyName;
        }

        public void setDesignation(String design) {
            designation = design;
        }

        public String getDesignation() {
            return designation;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName = fName;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lName) {
            lastName = lName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setProfileImage(String image) {
            profileimageBLOB = image;
        }

        public String getProfileImage() {
            return firstName;
        }

        // toString() method
        public String toString() {
            return accountID + "\t" + companyName + "\t" + designation + "\t\t"
                    + firstName + "\t" + lastName + "\t" + profileimageBLOB;
        }
    }
```

I make changes accordingly to @Gopal Rao, this is my above code, however I face a lot of error that I cannot understand, am I doing it correctly?

please advise, it is still not working

Comment: what do you mean by whole String?

Comment: where is your search logic/method?

Comment: He probably meant "instead of the toString() method". As for the solution, @GopalRao 's answers will work for exact matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this...

```
public User getUserByName(String firstName, String lastName) {
    synchronized (userList) {
        Iterator<User> iterator = userList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            User user = (User) iterator.next();
            if (user.getFirstName().equals(firstName)
                    && user.getLastName().equals(lastName)) {
                return user;
            }
        }
        // no user found
        return null;
    }
}


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private EditText firstNameEditText;
    private EditText lastNameEditText;
    private UserListAdapter<User> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        firstNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstNameEditText);
        lastNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastNameEditText);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayList<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();
        // add items to list
        adapter = new UserListAdapter<User>(this,
                R.layout.textview_layout, usersList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        firstNameEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus) {
                    adapter.setFilterMode(UserListAdapter.MODE_FILTER_BY_FIRST_NAME);
                }
            }
        });
        lastNameEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus) {
                    adapter.setFilterMode(UserListAdapter.MODE_FILTER_BY_LAST_NAME);
                }
            }
        });
        TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
        };

        firstNameEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        lastNameEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    }

    public static class UserListAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
        public static final int MODE_FILTER_BY_FIRST_NAME = 0xFEED;
        public static final int MODE_FILTER_BY_LAST_NAME = 0xDEAF;
        private List<T> objects;
        private int filterMode;

        public UserListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<T> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            init(objects);
        }

        public UserListAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                int textViewResourceId, T[] objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
            init(Arrays.asList(objects));
        }

        private void init(List<T> objects) {
            this.objects = objects;
        }

        public UserListAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
            init(objects);
        }

        public UserListAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
        }

        public UserListAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
            super(context, resource);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return new Filter() {

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                        FilterResults results) {
                    UserListAdapter.this.clear();
                    ArrayList<T> list = (ArrayList<T>) results.values;
                    UserListAdapter.this.addAll(list);
                    if (results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected synchronized FilterResults performFiltering(
                        CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
                    Iterator<T> iterator = objects.iterator();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        T t = (T) iterator.next();
                        User user = (User) t;
                        String s = null;
                        if (filterMode == MODE_FILTER_BY_FIRST_NAME) {
                            s = user.getFirstName();
                        } else if (filterMode == MODE_FILTER_BY_LAST_NAME) {
                            s = user.getLastName();
                        }
                        if (s.equals(constraint.toString())) {
                            list.add(t);
                        }
                    }
                    results.values = list;
                    results.count = list.size();
                    return results;
                }
            };
        }

        public int getFilterMode() {
            return filterMode;
        }

        public void setFilterMode(int filterMode) {
            this.filterMode = filterMode;
        }
    }

    public static class User {
        // attributes
        private String accountID;
        private String companyName;
        private String designation;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String profileimageBLOB;

        // behaviors
        public User() // default constructor
        {
            // attributes will be initialized to their default values
        }

        public User(String accID, String comName, String design, String fName,
                String lName, String image) // parameterized constructor
        {
            accountID = accID;
            companyName = comName;
            designation = design;
            firstName = fName;
            lastName = lName;
            profileimageBLOB = image;
        }

        // set and get methods
        public void setAccountID(String accID) {
            accountID = accID;
        }

        public String getAccountID() {
            return accountID;
        }

        public void setCompanyName(String comName) {
            companyName = comName;
        }

        public String getCompanyName() {
            return companyName;
        }

        public void setDesignation(String design) {
            designation = design;
        }

        public String getDesignation() {
            return designation;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName = fName;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lName) {
            lastName = lName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setProfileImage(String image) {
            profileimageBLOB = image;
        }

        public String getProfileImage() {
            return firstName;
        }

        // toString() method
        public String toString() {
            return accountID + "\t" + companyName + "\t" + designation + "\t\t"
                    + firstName + "\t" + lastName + "\t" + profileimageBLOB;
        }
    }
}
```

take care about synchronization...

Comment: This is not search function. it remove item from list . 

** Can you explain, what happen, if user remove all text from Edittext. it show previous list with all item?

Comment: Thanks, It only return one user but if two user name have first and last name and two character are same. 

ListView are make by List of user array not a single uaer object.  

Also, you do not tell me show he update userList in ListView and here need to call this function. 

Please edit you answer again and give more information.

Comment: So how should I edit in my current java code? Do I need to remove the textWatcher()?

Comment: Below is my version, I face a lot of error and it is not working at all.

Comment: @Ryan I didn't see your code. may be you are trying to edit my answer and adding your code. don't do that. add your code by editing your question...

Answer (score 0):

you need do custom search then you need to add custom ListView search function.

This is big example , what i give you this link. I think it help you.

> [Link](http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/forum/thread/550920/Tutorial-How-to-Add-search-function-to-custom-Listview)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to override `getFilter` in your adapter class Inside the `perforFiltering` method use 
some iterating method to get proper list of data.

Please follow below [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android)