# how to update listview based on edittext value in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have edittext and below that one listview now if need to search means based on text on edittext i need to update the list view.the listview values stored in arraylist

[image]

Comment: use filtering. if you are using `ArrayAdapter`, you can use `adpter.getFilter().filter(...)`...

Comment: can u explain some more on it, how to pass value from edittext and how  to get searched values

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678472/androidhow-to-do-a-search-on-the-first-name-and-last-name-only/20678661#20678661. It is similar to your question...

Comment: Not to demoralize or anything, try searching on google or SO before asking the question. This one from [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9418457/3315970)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the search function in my applicaton,hope u get him idea from it..

```
et_artists_searchWord.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            List<AdapterDTOArtist> list = filter(s.toString(),
                    mAdapterDTOsBackup, true);
            mAdapterDTOs.clear(); // <--- clear the list before add
            mAdapterDTOs.addAll(list); // <--- here is the double add if
                                        // you// do not clear before
            mLazyAdatper.setDataSet(mAdapterDTOs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

out side oncreate search method:

```
public static List<AdapterDTOArtist> filter(String string,
        Iterable<AdapterDTOArtist> iterable, boolean byName) {
    if (iterable == null)
        return new LinkedList<AdapterDTOArtist>();
    else {
        List<AdapterDTOArtist> collected = new LinkedList<AdapterDTOArtist>();
        Iterator<AdapterDTOArtist> iterator = iterable.iterator();
        if (iterator == null)
            return collected;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            AdapterDTOArtist item = iterator.next();
            // if(item.getmTag_Name().startsWith(string))
            if (item.getmTag_Name().toLowerCase().startsWith(string)){
                // if
                // (item.getmTag_Name().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(string))
                collected.add(item);
            }
            else if(item.getmTag_Name().toUpperCase().startsWith(string)){
                collected.add(item);
            }
        }
        return collected;
    }
}
```