# getFilter() for custom BaseAdapter Listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I know there are tens of questions similar to this on Stackoverflow but none of them solved my problem. I am using a custom `listview adapter` class in my app which extends `BaseAdapter`. I am using an `edittext` as the searchbar that will filter the `listview`.
Here is the custom BaseAdapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
Activity context;
String title[];
String description[];

public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, String[] title, String[] description) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return title.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtViewTitle;
    TextView txtViewDescription;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]);
    holder.txtViewDescription.setText(description[position]);

return convertView;
}

}
```

and here is where I implement it in my activity.

```
searchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            String searchedquery = cs.toString().replaceAll(" ", "");
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(searchedquery);//getFilter() problem
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

How do I make the custom `listview` filterable. Please help me with reference to the code given in my question. I am pretty much a beginner. Thanks!

I tried this code but its not working:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter  implements Filterable
{
Activity context;
String title[];
String description[];

public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, String[] title, String[] description) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return title.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtViewTitle;
    TextView txtViewDescription;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]);
    holder.txtViewDescription.setText(description[position]);

return convertView;
}
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            List<String> arrayListNames;
            arrayListNames = (List<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            Filter.FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<String> FilteredArrayNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> mDatabaseOfNames = null;
            // perform your search here using the searchConstraint String.

            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 0; i < mDatabaseOfNames.size(); i++) {
                String dataNames = mDatabaseOfNames.get(i);
                if (dataNames.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString()))  {
                    FilteredArrayNames.add(dataNames);
                }
            }

            results.count = FilteredArrayNames.size();
            results.values = FilteredArrayNames;
            Log.e("VALUES", results.values.toString());

            return results;
        }
    };

    return filter;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `BaseAdapter` implement `Filterable`. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android/14663821#14663821) answer.

Comment: I already saw that but having problems with getFilter() method. Can you please please post the code with reference to my question? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: If you look at the link, you will see that the answer has an **EDIT** where they provide code on how to implement `getFilter()`

Comment: I saw that but couldn't figure out what's `arrayListNames` and `mDatabaseOfNames`. Can you please explain it? the rest is fine. Thanks in advance again!

Comment: `arrayListNames` is a `List<String>` that contains the filtered results. `mDatabaseOfNames` is probably another `List<String>` that contains the unfiltered data.

Comment: I did it but its not working please check my updated question.