# need to clear adapter from listview

Tags: android, arrays, listview, adapter, android-adapter

i am trying to clear adapter from list view but nothing happen
here it  is my code

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    search_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    emptyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);

    bookListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    // Get a reference to the ConnectivityManager to check state of network connectivity
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    // Get details on the currently active default data network
    final NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    search_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                new GetBook().execute(BOOK_REQUEST_URL);
            } else {
```

//here need to clear adapter but nothin happen

```
                emptyTextView.setText(R.string.NoConnect);
                bookListView.setEmptyView(emptyTextView);
                bookAdapter.clear();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Your implementation of Adapter is wrong... Fx you are extending from ArrayAdapter and overriding the getCount but not clear. Common mistake is to store data again inside custom ArrayAdapter while ArrayAdapter stores it already.

Comment: You need to read a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775171/the-clear-in-custom-listview-adapter-also-updates-the-list-data

Answer (score 0):

after `bookAdapter.clear()` include `bookAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in your code

Comment: when press button search app crash when no internet connection

Comment: You check state but you need to write logic if there is no internet.

Comment: @Stanojkovic  can you give me example

Comment: @Stanojkovic
this my code 
else if (networkInfo == null && !networkInfo.isConnected()){

                    emptyTextView.setText(R.string.NoConnect);
                    bookListView.setEmptyView(emptyTextView);
                    bookAdapter.clear();
                    bookAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.e("this error","er");

                }

Answer (score 0):

You have to call notifyDataSetChanged() method for your adapter that will notifies the adapter that the data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

Comment: when press button search app crash when no internet connectio

Comment: Add a crash log please

Comment: 06-03 23:17:51.232 5965-5965/com.example.mohammedragab.booklisting E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.example.mohammedragab.booklisting, PID: 5965
                                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.mohammedragab.booklisting.BookAdapter.clear()' on a null object reference

this give me error

Comment: Your BookAdapter object is null

Comment: what this mean? how i fix it

Comment: Here you have a nice tutorial: [Android Working with Recycler View](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)

Answer (score 0):

@mohammedragabmohammedborik, here is an example for internet logic.

```
final ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
    // you are online and do your stuff
} else {
    // not online, show MessageBox or something else
}
```

Add this permission to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I cannot help you with `adapter.clear()`, you have not provided adapter code.

Comment: thanks for your offer best
but i make this defenition in my code