# ListView filtering not working

Tags: android, listview

I have created a list view in android and add edit text above the list and when the user enter text the list will be filtered according to user input but notworking :
[image]

```
            @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            MainActivity.this.myadpt.getFilter().filter(arg0);

        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the `Filter` object and its implementation of `filter()`?

Comment: `override` the `toString()` in your model and return the `title`

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, arraylist);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        adapter.filter(text);
    }
});
```

- see this one: [List View Filter Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android)