# Issues with Filtering listview with edittext

Tags: android, listview, filter, android-edittext

Hello I'm working on an app which has an edittext to search for items on the listview. If the user types a letter in the edittext the listview is getting filtered perfectlty.Have used Adapter also.Now i have following issues:

1)when i m clearing letters edittext my listview is not getting Updated..

2) if i enter wrong letter or letter which does not corrorsponds to any item of a listview the listview is getting clear.

Have gone thorugh  exmaples in SO
[Android filter listview custom adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475725/android-filter-listview-custom-adapter)

And googled also for same problem but not getting solved it..Plz anybody help me..

Here is my code:

```
    package com.AAAAA.AAAAA;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

    import com.AAAAA.adapter.UpdateSingleItemViewActivity;
    import com.AAAAA.adapter.UpdatesAdapterList;
    import com.AAAAA.local.database.DBController;
    import com.AAAAA.AAAAA.AAAAA.constant.Constant;
    import com.AAAAA.AAAAA.AAAAA.utils.Utility;

    public class Cardiology_updates extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
            OnRefreshListener {
        EditText et ;
        private Context appContext;
        // ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        private Dialog dialog;
        private boolean isFinish = false;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jsonobject;
        JSONArray jsonArray;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> UpdatesHmList;
        public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> FinalLocalDataList;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> LocalDataList;
        DBController controller = new DBController(this);
        HashMap<String, String> queryValues;
        ListView list;
        UpdatesAdapterList adapter;
        public static String UpdateID = "UpdateID";
        public static String UpdateTitle = "Title";
        /*
         * public static String UpdateDescription = "Description"; public static
         * String POPULATION = "UpdateDate"; public static String UpdateImage =
         * "Photo";
         */

        public static String UpdateDescription = "Description";
        public static String POPULATION = "Title";
        public static String UpdateImage = "Complete_imagePath";

        public static String Complete_imagePath;
        public static String Title;
        public static String Description;

        SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
        private ProgressBar progressbar;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_cardiology_updates);
    //      controller.deleteAllJsonData();
            appContext = this;
            animationView();
            initComponent();

        }

        private void animationView() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading);
        }

        private void initComponent() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
            swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
            swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                    android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                    android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                    android.R.color.holo_red_light);


            dialog = new Dialog(appContext);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog);
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01)).setOnClickListener(this);
            ((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk)).setOnClickListener(this);

            new GetUpdatesInfo().execute();

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (v.getId() == R.id.Button01) {

                finish();
                // finishActivity() ;
            } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnOk) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                if (isFinish) {
                    this.finish();
                }

            }
        }

        public class GetUpdatesInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                if (progressbar.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                // Create an array
                UpdatesHmList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
                String url = null;

                url = Constant.serverUrl + "/GetUpdateList";
                result = Utility.postParamsAndfindJSON(url);
                Log.e("result doInBackground", "" + result);
                if (!(result == null)) {
                    try {
                        controller.deleteAllJsonData();
                        // Locate the array name in JSON
                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            // Retrive JSON Objects
                            map.put("UpdateID", jsonobject.getString("UpdateID"));
                            map.put("Title", jsonobject.getString("Title"));

                            String Upadates_Photo = jsonobject.optString("Photo")
                                    .toString();

                            String Complete_imagePath = Constant.prifixserverUrl
                                    + Upadates_Photo;
                            String Title = jsonobject.getString("Title").toString();
                            String Description = jsonobject
                                    .getString("Description").toString();

                            String noHtml = Description.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");

                            String parseResponse = noHtml.replaceAll("&nbsp;", "");

                            map.put("Photo", Complete_imagePath);
                            map.put("Description", Description);
                            map.put("UpdateDate",
                                    jsonobject.getString("UpdateDate"));

                            Log.e("UpdateID ",
                                    " "
                                            + jsonobject.getString("UpdateID")
                                                    .toString());
                            Log.e("Title ", " "
                                    + jsonobject.getString("Title").toString());
                            Log.e("Complete_imagePath ",
                                    " " + Complete_imagePath.toString());

                            Log.e("Description ", " " + parseResponse);

                            Log.e("UpdateDate ",
                                    " "
                                            + jsonobject.getString("UpdateDate")
                                                    .toString());

                            queryValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            queryValues.put("Complete_imagePath",
                                    Complete_imagePath);
                            queryValues.put("Title", Title);
                            queryValues.put("Description", Description);
                            controller.insertAllJsonData(queryValues);
                            // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                            UpdatesHmList.add(map);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
                if (progressbar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                /*
                 * if (result == null) { //mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                 * localalldata();
                 * 
                 * }
                 */
                localalldata();

                /*
                 * list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_Upadates); // Pass the
                 * results into ListViewAdapter.java adapter = new
                 * UpdatesAdapterList(Cardiology_updates.this, FinalLocalDataList);
                 * // Set the adapter to the ListView list.setAdapter(adapter);
                 */

                // Close the progressdialog
                // mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                 getSomeData();
    //              localalldata();
                    swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }, 5000);

        }

        protected void getSomeData() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // localalldata();
            new GetUpdatesInfo().execute();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            /*
             * if (LocalDataList == null) { Log.e("LocalDataList inside if ",
             * "LocalDataList inside if "); new GetUpdatesInfo().execute();
             * 
             * } else { // adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
             * Log.e("LocalDataList else ", "LocalDataList else  ");
             * 
             * adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); }
             */

        }

        private void localalldata() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LocalDataList = controller.getAllJsonData();
            FinalLocalDataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            for (HashMap<String, String> hashMap : LocalDataList) {
                System.out.println(hashMap.keySet());
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                for (String key : hashMap.keySet()) {
                    System.out.println(hashMap.get(key));

                    Complete_imagePath = hashMap.get("Complete_imagePath");
                    Title = hashMap.get("Title");
                    Description = hashMap.get("Description");

                    map.put("Complete_imagePath", Complete_imagePath);
                    map.put("Title", Title);
                    map.put("Description", Description);
                    Log.v("All Json CodiateUpdate Title", "" + Complete_imagePath);
                    Log.v("All Json CodiateUpdate Title", "" + Title);
                }
                FinalLocalDataList.add(map);
            }
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_Upadates);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new UpdatesAdapterList(Cardiology_updates.this,
                    FinalLocalDataList);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
            // Capture Text in EditText
            et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    adapter.filter(arg0.toString());
         }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                        int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {
                    //String text = et.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                    //adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);
                }
            });

             }
             }
```

Here is my Adapter:

```
package com.AAAA.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.AAAA.AAAA.Cardiology_updates;
import com.AAAA.AAAA.R;
import com.AAAA.imageloader.ImageLoader;

public class UpdatesAdapterList extends BaseAdapter {
    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Activity activity;
    //HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> filterData;
    public UpdatesAdapterList(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());
        filterData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        filterData.addAll(this.data);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return filterData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return filterData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview_updateitem, null);
            holder.UpdateTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUpdatetitle);
            holder.UpdateImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_UpdateImage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.UpdateTitle.setText(filterData.get(position).get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateTitle));

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(filterData.get(position).get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateImage), holder.UpdateImage);
        // Capture ListView item click
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Get the position
                //resultp = data.get(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateSingleItemViewActivity.class);
                // Pass all data rank
                intent.putExtra("UpdateTile", filterData.get(position).get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateTitle));
                // Pass all data country
                intent.putExtra("UpdateDescription", filterData.get(position).get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateDescription));
                // Pass all data population
                intent.putExtra("population",filterData.get(position).get(Cardiology_updates.POPULATION));
                // Pass all data flag
                intent.putExtra("UpdateImage", filterData.get(position).get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateImage));
                // Start SingleItemView Class
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }); return convertView;

    }

    class ViewHolder{
        TextView UpdateTitle;
        ImageView UpdateImage;
    }

    public void filter(String constraint) {
        filterData.clear();
        if (constraint.length() == 0) {
            filterData.addAll(data);
        }else{
            for (HashMap<String,String> row: data) {
                if(row.get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateTitle).toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())){
                    filterData.add(row);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Activity opens on cliking listview items:

```
package com.AAAAA.adapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.AAAAA.AAAAA.Cardiology_updates;
import com.AAAAA.AAAAA.R;

public class UpdateSingleItemViewActivity extends Activity  {
     int position;
    String UpdateTile;
    String UpdateDescription;
    String population;
    String UpdateImage;
    //String position;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PagerAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_single_item_view);

        Log.e("UpdateSingleItemViewActivity class",
                "UpdateSingleItemViewActivity class");
        /*
         * WebView webview = new WebView(this); setContentView(webview);
         */
        Button btnback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        btnback.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });


        //WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        // Get the result of rank
        UpdateTile = i.getStringExtra("UpdateTile");
        // Get the result of country
        UpdateDescription = i.getStringExtra("UpdateDescription");
        // Get the result of population
        population = i.getStringExtra("population");
        // Get the result of flag
        UpdateImage = i.getStringExtra("UpdateImage");
        //i.putExtra("POSITION_KEY", position);
        position = i.getExtras().getInt("position");
        //webview.loadData(UpdateDescription, "text/html", null);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_layout);
        // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(UpdateSingleItemViewActivity.this, Cardiology_updates.FinalLocalDataList);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }

    }
```

its Corrosponding adapter:

```
    package com.AAAAA.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.AAAAA.AAAAA.Cardiology_updates;
import com.AAAAA.AAAAA.R;
import com.AAAAA.imageloader.ImageLoader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    String UpdateTile;
    String UpdateDescription;
    //String population;
    String UpdateImage;
    String position;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
      private Activity activity;
    //HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
      ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> filterData;
    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        filterData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        filterData.addAll(this.data);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return filterData.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return filterData.get(position);
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        WebView webview;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
                false);
        //resultp =data.get(position);

        webview=(WebView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        //webview.setText(webview[position]);
        webview.loadData(filterData.get(position).get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateDescription), "text/html", null);

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
        return itemView;

}

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);

    }
}
```

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422072/searchview-in-listview-having-a-custom-adapter/23422665#23422665

Comment: Thanks but M not working with SearchView want to do it with Edittext...

Comment: Okay then check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925252/how-can-i-add-auto-searchview-with-listview/26928942#26928942

Answer (score 0):

When used custom adapter always try to implement [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) design pattern for ListView performance and use custom filter function instead Filterable implementation :

Custom filter funcation required two array list one is filterable data list and another one is for orignal data list :

```
public void filter(String constraint) {
   filterData.clear();
   if (constraint.length() == 0) {
       filterData.addAll(orignalData);
   }else{
       for (HashMap<String,String> row: orignalData) {
            if(row.get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateTitle).toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())){
               filterData.add(row);
            }
        }
   }
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Example :**

```
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        adapter.filter(arg0.toString());
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,int arg2, int arg3) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {

    }
});

public class UpdatesAdapterList extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> filterData;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> orignalData;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public UpdatesAdapterList(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> orignalData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.orignalData = orignalData;
        filterData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        filterData.addAll(this.orignalData);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return filterData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return filterData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview_updateitem, null);
            holder.UpdateTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUpdatetitle);
            holder.UpdateImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_UpdateImage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.UpdateTitle.setText(filterData.get(position).get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateTitle));

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(filterData.get(position).get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateImage), holder.UpdateImage);
        // Capture ListView item click
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateSingleItemViewActivity.class);
                // Pass all data rank
                intent.putExtra("UpdateTile", filterData.get(position).get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateTitle));
                // Pass all data country
                intent.putExtra("UpdateDescription", filterData.get(position).get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateDescription));
                // Pass all data population
                intent.putExtra("population",filterData.get(position).get(Cardiology_updates.POPULATION));
                // Pass all data flag
                intent.putExtra("UpdateImage", filterData.get(position).get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateImage));
                // Start SingleItemView Class
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        TextView UpdateTitle;
        ImageView UpdateImage;
    }

    public void filter(String constraint) {
        filterData.clear();
        if (constraint.length() == 0) {
            filterData.addAll(orignalData);
        }else{
            for (HashMap<String,String> row: orignalData) {
                if(row.get(Cardiology_updates.UpdateTitle).toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())){
                    filterData.add(row);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Haresh u solved my problem..But have only one problem When I search the list and THEN click on an Item, it doesn't open the activity associated with the filtered results. It opens up an Activity related to the Item at that position in Original list.Can u guide me for this issue.

Comment: @Test,have you seen on convertView item click  i have pass data from filterData list not from orignal so i think there is no problem happen with such case or have you implement list item click listenere out side adapter ?

Comment: No it is in the Adapter class only..m updating my new code with changes told by u...

Comment: @Test,remove resultp related code from adapter which no longer required in new code.

Comment: Example Original List : AA, BA, CC, DA, ED, FF

Search : 'A' Filtered results: AA, BA, DA

But when I click on item DA it opens up the Activity for CC

Comment: @Test,First of all if search 'A' then only one result will came which AA becz see in filter method we compare startwith not contain.

Comment: ok sorry for my mistake..ya it will show the result starting from alphabet..Example Original List : AA, AB, CC, AD, ED, FF Search : 'A' Filtered results: AA, AB, AD But when I click on item AD it opens up the Activity for CC ...this is my query actually

Comment: Sorry bro but its my official work so cant share it.:(.i found same query on SO...but m not getting  any kind of solution for it..here it is...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562556/filtered-listview-onitemclick-returns-item-at-original-position

Comment: Np as per my opinion my code work perfectly and i check your given case with my code so good luck.

Comment: want to know whether The code which i have updated is correct???or is there any mistake...bcoz this link is not able to help me.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562556/filtered-listview-onitemclick-returns-item-at-original-position