# Change ArrayAdapter while filling up AutoCompleteTextView onTextChanged

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I found many questions like this, but no answer. Is it possible to change the `ArrayList` of the adapter while `AutoCompleteTextView` is being typed?

```
 private void setUpAutocomplete() {
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
    final AutoCompleteTextView textView = autocompleteTV;
    textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            adapter.clear();
            ArrayList<String> locations=gAPI.autocomplete(s.toString());
            adapter.addAll(locations);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android

Comment: You want to tell me that the only possible option is to create edit text?

Comment: AutoCompleteTextView extends EditText, and no just i give you an easy option =)

Comment: Using AutiCompleteTextView with a TextWatcher is a mistake,  you should use filtering mechanism already builtin in the adapters

Comment: All right then, how may I change arraylist of the adapter on go? Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: What do you need that arraylist for?

Comment: For autocomplete of users search.. google api location. But I have found something in google documentation, I am going to try it.

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858843/how-to-dynamically-add-suggestions-to-autocompletetextview-with-preserving-chara how easily it can be done to use a wikipedua web service with ACTV

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. The following code retrieves places from the Google Places API and populates the an ArrayAdapter, which changes as the text in the AutocompleteTextView changes.

```
// declare this variable globally in your activity so that it can be
//referenced and updated in the inner class (public void onResult(...))
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; 

AutoCompleteTextView locationText = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.location_text);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    locationText.setAdapter(adapter);

    locationText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            String query = s.toString();

//mMap is a GoogleMap object. Alternatively, you can initialize a
//LatLngBounds object directly through its constructor
            LatLngBounds bounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

            AutocompleteFilter filter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                    .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_NONE)
                    .build();

            PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> autocompleteResult =
                    Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, query,
                            bounds, filter);

            autocompleteResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<AutocompletePredictionBuffer>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < autocompletePredictions.getCount(); i++) {
                        adapter.add(autocompletePredictions.get(0).getFullText(null).toString());
                    }
                    autocompletePredictions.release();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

        }
```

Below is the XML code for the AutocompleteTextView:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/location_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:hint="Search location..." />
```