# Search Filter is not working

Tags: android, json, arraylist, filter

Nothing happening even i am entering exact "key" name in EditText whereas it has to be show only that record in a list.

Filtering is not working, this is how my JSON looks like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Era Locksmith",
      "key": "EraLoc2015"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Mac Garage Door",
      "key": "MacGdr2015"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am extending ArrayAdapter<....> and implementing Filterable

**CompanyListAdapter.java:**

```
    public class CompanyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Company> implements Filterable {

    private Context context;
    ArrayList<Company> products;
    SharedPreference sharedPreference;

    private ArrayList<Company> filteredCompanies;
    private CompanyFilter mFilter = new CompanyFilter();

    public CompanyListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Company> products) {
        super(context, R.layout.company_list_item, products);
        this.context = context;
        this.products = products;
        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView productNameTxt;
        TextView productKeyTxt;
        ImageView favoriteImg;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Company getItem(int position) {
        return products.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.company_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.productNameTxt = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_pdt_name);
            holder.productKeyTxt = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_pdt_price);
            holder.favoriteImg = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Company product = (Company) getItem(position);
        holder.productNameTxt.setText(product.getName());
        holder.productKeyTxt.setText(product.getPrice() + "");

        /*If a product exists in shared preferences then set heart_red drawable
         * and set a tag*/
        if (checkFavoriteItem(product)) {
            holder.favoriteImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
            holder.favoriteImg.setTag("red");
        } else {
            holder.favoriteImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
            holder.favoriteImg.setTag("grey");
        }

        return convertView;
    }   

    /*Checks whether a particular product exists in SharedPreferences*/
    public boolean checkFavoriteItem(Company checkProduct) {
        boolean check = false;
        List<Company> favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites(context);
        if (favorites != null) {
            for (Company product : favorites) {
                if (product.equals(checkProduct)) {
                    check = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return check;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Company product) {
        super.add(product);
        products.add(product);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Company product) {
        super.remove(product);
        products.remove(product);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class CompanyFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<Company> list = products;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<Company> nlist = new ArrayList<Company>(count);

            Company filterableCompany;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableCompany = list.get(i);
                if (filterableCompany.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(filterableCompany);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredCompanies = (ArrayList<Company>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

Using EditText to accept **"key"**

**CompanyListActivity.java:**

```
EditText filterList = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editKey);
        filterList.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                productListAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

I am using code provided by @Leigh

Comment: possible duplicate of [List View Filter Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `implement Filterable`? 
Try something like this:

Make your adapter class look like this:

```
public class CompanyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Company> implements Filterable {

    private List<Company> companies;
    private List<Company> filteredCompanies;
    private CompanyFilter mFilter = new CompanyFilter();

    private Context context;
    SharedPreference sharedPreference;

    public CompanyListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Company> products) {
        super(context, R.layout.company_list_item, products);
        this.context = context;
        this.products = products;
        this.filteredCompanies = products;
        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return filteredCompanies == null 0 : filteredCompanies.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Company getItem(int position) {
        return filteredCompanies.get(position);
    }

    @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }
}
```

Next go ahead and create a CompanyFilter:

```
private class CompanyFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        final List<Company> list = companies;

        int count = list.size();
        final ArrayList<Company> nlist = new ArrayList<Company>(count);

        Company filterableCompany;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            filterableCompany = list.get(i);
            if (filterableCompany.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                nlist.add(filterableCompany);
            }
        }

        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredCompanies = (ArrayList<Company>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This way you get to apply your filter to any number of fields. Note I am using the `getName()` of the company class to apply the filter in my example.

EDIT:
TO use this in an `Activity` / `Fragment` for searching you can add a `TextWatcher` to your `EditText` and apply the filter `onTextChanged`. Something like this:

```
txtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: great code but little bit confuse how this code connected to my EditText ?

Comment: @Sun see my edit which gives you an example of how you could to use the filter against your adapter.

Comment: @Sun see my updates, you should now use `filteredCompanies` instead of `companies` (previously `products`). You should also use `filteredCompanies` in your `getView()` also.

Comment: once my data parsed i want to cache for the future even internet is not available and whenever any new data comes i want to fetch>cache that - will you help me ?

Comment: @Sun I can help but you should probably start a new question as that is an unrelated issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make your adapter implement `Filterable` like this:

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    @Override
        public Filter getFilter() { ...}
```

try to look at this answer:
[List View Filter Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14663821/1787109)