# How to add a functional search bar to a navigation drawer?

Tags: android, filter, navigation-drawer, searchbar

I am developing a wallpaper app that loads it's images from Picasa I have a Navigation drawer that retrieves it's items name from  the Picasa album names
(I am using the source code of this tutorial [Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/08/android-building-free-wallpapers-app-part-2/) ), so I want to add a search bar that filters the items in the navigation drawer, any idea on how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android

Answer (score 3):

It might be a little late. But may help others.

1. Add an EditText to navigation Drawer.(activity_main.xml)

   ```
   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:hint="search" 
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
      android:inputType="text" >
    </EditText>
   ```
2. add a TextWatcher to editText. (Add the following lines to `onCreate`)

   ```
      final EditText inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

       inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           //You should use the adapter in NavigationDrawerFragment
           NavigationDrawerFragment.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

       }

       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
               int arg3) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }
   });
   ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your navigation drawer a `Fragment` that contains an [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html), which implements [`Filterable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html). This adapter would contain list of your Picasa album names.

For the search box, a simple [`EditText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) would do the job. Register a [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) that would listen to text change events and trigger [`Filter.filter()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html#filter(java.lang.CharSequence)) on a `Filter` returned from your [`ArrayAdapter.getFilter()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getFilter()) with input text as query.

Comment: Can you explain it no more details with examples, please?

Comment: It's a bit tedious to construct a fully working example. My answer only gives the direction, you can try to Google for tutorial, e.g. http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html