# How to add ListView item on Edit Texts text change event

Tags: android, android-listview

I have edit text & listview at layout, what I want add listview item value on edit texts text change event. Suppose I started typing in edit text that character will shown as list item in listview.

How could I achieve that..?

My Base adapters getView() Code as following.. I'm creating text views programatically,

```
    TTDemo msg = (TTDemo) this.getItem(position);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, group, false);

        viewHolder.relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.root_rl);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp =  new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                                                                                                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);;

        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        rlp.setMargins(0, 8, 0, 8);

        bg = new TextView(context);
        bg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        bg.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        bg.setTextSize(20f);
        bg.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        bg.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        bg.setLayoutParams(rlp);
        viewHolder.relativeLayout.addView(bg);

        textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setTextSize(20f);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        textView.setLayoutParams(rlp);
        viewHolder.relativeLayout.addView(textView);

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.zoom_out);
        bg.setAnimation(animation);

        viewHolder.message = msg;
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    if(msg.getName() != null)
    {
        bg.setText("." + msg.getName() + ".");
        textView.setText("" + msg.getName());
    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder = null;
    }

    return viewHolder.relativeLayout;
```

And on EditTexts text change event,

```
et.addTextChangedListener(new new TextWatcher()
{
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence sequence, int start, int before, int count) 
    {
        if(sequence != null && sequence.length() > 0)
        {
           list.add(al);
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           listView.setSelection(list.size()-1);
        }
    }
});
```

Model Class, al is an instance of this class ( list.add(al) in textChange method)

```
public class TTDemo 
{
    public String name;
    public int isFinished;

    public TTDemo(String name, int isFinished) 
    {
       this.name = name;
       this.isFinished = isFinished;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use textWatcher for your textView and notify data set change to your adapter in onTextChanged method of watcher...

Comment: @HarmeetSingh, I posted my implementation.. Suggest me proper away..

Comment: use adapter.getFilter().filter() method inside afterTextChanged

Comment: Any other detailed tutorial or link which I can get more cleared !!!

Comment: What's `al` variable that's passed to `list.add(al)` method?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly , your trying to filter a listView.
If so, add a EditText field to the layout and add an **OnTextChangeListener** to your EditText field and inside its callback method apply filter to your listview's adapter. And do remember, if you want to filter a Custom BaseAdapter, make sure you implement a filterable interface for the Custom BaseAdapter.

For additional information, you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android) question.