# Android: ArrayList - filtering

Tags: android, arraylist, filter

I try added filter to ArrayList (data is from json/php script on my server). I find but I not see resolving...

I try more sample codes and more resolving, but nothing works.

```
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        list = new ArrayList<FriendItem>();
        adapter = new FriendAllAdapter(context, list);


        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        String filename = getResources().getString(R.string.friendalllist_php);
        asyncLoadVolley = new AsyncLoadVolley(context, filename);
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(Constant.ID, Sessions.getUserId(context));
        asyncLoadVolley.setBasicNameValuePair(map);
        asyncLoadVolley.setOnAsyncTaskListener(asyncTaskListener);

        connectionDetector = new ConnectionDetector(context);

        if(savedInstanceState==null) {

        }
        //enables filtering for the contents of the given ListView
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClickListener);

        EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
        myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        //here added filter... 

        }
        });
```

Comment: Please try to condense your code to the relevant part.

Comment: done, I condense my code....

Comment: I think this solution help you.

  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14663821/4369802

Comment: Thanks, I try it, but maybe it's more complicated for me...

Comment: Sorry, but I not understand... very hard to me ... :(

Answer (score 1):

For example:
You have a model - FriendItem

```
public class FriendItem {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    //.....

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

and have an adapter - FriendAllAdapter.
In this adapter you should implement **Filterable** interface.
You"ll need to Override  getFilter() method and return new object of Filter class (android.widget.Filter).

- In **performFiltering()** method your need return FilterResults object with count of filtered elements and value - list of elements. Also in this method you need to realize the algorithm comparison of the search query to values in your FriendItem (list item). In my example I search FriendItem(s) which fields (*firstName* or *lastName*) contains text in my editText.
  Input parameter is a CharSequence object which you set in **onTextChanged()** method on added textChangeListener to your EditText.

  ```
  myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

          adapter.getFilter().filter(s); 

      }
  });
  ```
- In **publishResults()** method your get filtering result your need cast results.values to List and replace your list to filtering result.

  ```
  public class FriendAllAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {       

      private List<FriendItem> list;
      private final List<FriendItem> fullList = new ArrayList<>();

      public FriendAllAdapter(Context context, List<FriendItem> list) {

          //...... your code

          this.list = list;
          fullList.addAll(list);
      }


      //...... your code

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          //... your code
      }

      @Override
      public Filter getFilter() {
          Filter filter = new Filter() {
              @Override
              protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                  FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                      if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) { // if your editText field is empty, return full list of FriendItem
                          results.count = fullList.size();
                          results.values = fullList;
                      } else {
                          List<FriendItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                          constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase(); // if we ignore case
                          for (FriendItem item : fullList) {
                              String firstName = item.getFirstName().toLowerCase(); // if we ignore case
                              String lastName = item.getLastName().toLowerCase(); // if we ignore case
                              if (firstName.contains(constraint.toString()) || lastName.contains(constraint.toString())) {
                                  filteredList.add(item); // added item witch contains our text in EditText
                              }
                          }

                          results.count = filteredList.size(); // set count of filtered list
                          results.values = filteredList; // set filtered list
                      }
                  return results; // return our filtered list
              }

              @Override
              protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                      list = (List<FriendItem>) results.values; // replace list to filtered list 
                      notifyDataSetChanged(); // refresh adapter
              }
          };
          return filter;
      }
  }
  ```

I think you`ll understand it.
P.S. sorry for my English.