# android Search Listview SimpleCursorAdapter not working

Tags: android, listview, search, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to do autosearch using a searchview in a listview. Listview is populated with multiple items in a row. But the OnqueryListener is not firing anything.

Below is the sample of how am tring to do.

```
cursor = db.getAllRows();
        String[] storeFrom = new String[]{SQLiteHandler.KEY_ID, SQLiteHandler.KEY_NAME, SQLiteHandler.KEY_AGE, SQLiteHandler.KEY_GENDER, SQLiteHandler.KEY_HEIGHT, SQLiteHandler.KEY_WEIGHT};
        int[] toView = new int[]{R.id.tvId, R.id.tvName, R.id.tvAge, R.id.tvGender, R.id.tvHeight, R.id.tvWeight};
        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.customlist, cursor, storeFrom, toView, 0);
        personList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        personList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        searchText = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
        searchText.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text)
            {
                cursorAdapter.getFilter().filter(text);
                cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: For one you should be returning `true` if you handled those events.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should be setting the adapter and the `OnQueryTextListener` to the `SearchView` object... I may be wrong though.

Comment: all ypu need to do is to setup FilterQueryProvider

Answer (score 0):

I think u should fire Database Query every time in the method OnQueryTextChange and than call NotifyDataSetChange() method. Same problem was with me and i solved that with this. Here is the code snipped;

```
@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method

        if (!newText.trim().isEmpty()) {
Cursor cursor = dbHelper
                .searchByBrandText((newText != null ? newText: "@@@@"));

        if (cursor != null) {
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    brandOrCompositionNameArray.add(cursor.getString(0));

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}   customAdapterSuggestiveListView = new CustomAdapterSuggestiveListView(
                    SearchActivity.this, brandOrCompositionNameArray);
            brandOrcompositionNameList
                    .setAdapter(customAdapterSuggestiveListView);
}}
```

Comment: can you give a sample, if you could

Comment: I don't think this is the case, OP says `onQueryTextChange` isn't being called.

Answer (score -1):

A searchView that will work for you [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhNZpFdLJFQ&feature=youtu.be&t=1159),

If your listAdapter is extended to base adapter please follow this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14663821/2509009)

Comment: links could be broken or video not found after a while

Comment: [YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhNZpFdLJFQ)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhNZpFdLJFQ)