# Search bar to search a listView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, android-search

I have made an app that has a list of insurance companies using a `listView`. The `listView` is populated using an array adapter. I want to be able to search through this list with a search bar and only return an insurance company that is searched for. I have fallowed a tutorial however it doesn't filter the insurance companies. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong

Here is my code so far

insurance.xml

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"

/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="107dp">
    </ListView>
```

myList.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:background="#26BFDA">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"

        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6"

        android:orientation="vertical"

        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/nextarrow"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Insurance.java

```
public class Insurance extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> newadapter;
    EditText inputSearch;
    String[] itemname ={
            "AA",
            "Acorn",
            "Admiral",



    };

    Integer[] imgid= {
            R.drawable.aa,
            R.drawable.acorn,
            R.drawable.admiral,


    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_insurance);

        CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        newadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.mylist, R.id.item, itemname);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        list.setAdapter(newadapter);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                Insurance.this.newadapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String Slecteditem = itemname[+position];
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (Slecteditem.toString() == "AA") {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:028 9032 2232"));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (Slecteditem.toString() == "Carrot") {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:028 9032 2265"));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: See the EDIT part of the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14663821/4706693

Comment: You set the adapter (CustomListAdapter) to ListView while you filter in newadapter (ArrayAdapter).