# Android getting wrong position after filter listview using SearchView

Tags: android, listview

I am new to Android. I implemented SearchView with filter mode in Listview. When I click on an item, it opens a new activity getting all data word, definition, examle. It Works fine. But after the listview is filtered and click on an item, show a new activity getting wrong position from the data. I don't know how to solve this. I need some help.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    // Declare Variables
    ListView list;
    SearchView mSearchView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String[] definition;
    String[] word;
    String[] example;
    int[] flag;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

        // Generate sample data into string arrays
        definition = new String[] { "loira burra", 
                                    "arrasa-corações" };

        word = new String[] { "bimbo", 
                              "heartthrob" };

        example = new String[] { "She's a real bimbo.", 
                                 "He's a real heartthrob." };

        flag = new int[] { R.drawable.bimbo, 
                           R.drawable.heartthrob };

        // Locate the ListView in listview_main.xml
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);


        // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, word);

        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

         list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
         setupSearchView();
        // Capture ListView item click
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleItemView.class);
                // Pass all data definition
                i.putExtra("definition", definition);
                // Pass all data word
                i.putExtra("word", word);
                // Pass all data example
                i.putExtra("example", example);
                // Pass all data flag
                i.putExtra("flag", flag);
                // Pass a single position
                i.putExtra("position", position);
                // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
                startActivity(i);
            }

        });


    }

    private void setupSearchView() {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true); 
        mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            list.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            list.setFilterText(newText.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

ListView Adapter

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    String[] definition;
    String[] word;
    String[] example;
    int[] flag;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] definition, String[] word,
            String[] example, int[] flag) {
        this.context = context;
        this.definition = definition;
        this.word = word;
        this.example = example;
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return definition.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Declare Variables
        TextView txtdefinition;
        TextView txtword;
        TextView txtexample;
        ImageView imgflag;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        txtdefinition = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.definition);
        txtword = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.word);
        txtexample = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.example);
        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        txtdefinition.setText(definition[position]);
        txtword.setText(word[position]);
        txtexample.setText(example[position]);

        // Capture position and set to the ImageView
        imgflag.setImageResource(flag[position]);

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

SingleItemActivity

```
public class SingleItemView extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView txtdefinition;
    TextView txtword;
    TextView txtexample;
    ImageView imgflag;
    String[] definition;
    String[] word;
    String[] example;
    int[] flag;
    int position;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);
        // Retrieve data from MainActivity on listview item click
        Intent i = getIntent();
        // Get a single position
        position = i.getExtras().getInt("position");
        // Get the list of definition
        definition = i.getStringArrayExtra("definition");
        // Get the list of word
        word = i.getStringArrayExtra("word");
        // Get the list of example
        example = i.getStringArrayExtra("example");
        // Get the list of flag
        flag = i.getIntArrayExtra("flag");

        // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
        txtdefinition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.definition);
        txtword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);
        txtexample = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.example);

        // Locate the ImageView in singleitemview.xml
        imgflag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flag);

        // Load the text into the TextViews followed by the position
        txtdefinition.setText(definition[position]);
        txtword.setText(word[position]);
        txtexample.setText(example[position]);

        // Load the image into the ImageView followed by the position
        imgflag.setImageResource(flag[position]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filter the data directly from the adapter by implementing Filterable interface,
   you will need to add filtering code in performFiltering method.
   and do filter by calling the method **adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);**

you can see more details here:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android)