# Search an ArrayList Model

Tags: java, android

I want to get all items that contains the search input based on itemName. In c#, I can use lambda, but I could not find any references for android.

Here is the model class:

```
public class ModelItem {
    public long itemId;
    public String itemName;
    public double price;
}
```

Here is my list:

```
public static ArrayList<ModelItem> items;
```

I will use the list to get the items. Thank you in advance.

Comment: show full code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code

```
public void getAllItems(ArrayList<ModelItem> items, String searchItem) {
for(ModelItem item : items) {
 if(item.getItemName().contains(searchItem)) {
    // here you are getting item which matches inside your list
}
}
```

Comment: since you were the first one, can you enhance the "equal" part to contains?

Comment: sure, my mistake

Answer (score 2):

First step, copy items into `tempList`

```
private ArrayList<ModelItem> items; // You have data into this list
private ArrayList<ModelItem> tempData = new ArrayList<>();
for (ModelItem item : items) {
    tempData.add(item);
}
```

This is to filter items based on query

```
public void filter(String query) {
   items.clear();
   if (query.length() > 0) {
       for (ModelItem currItem : tempData) {
          // Add data into list, if item is having query string
          if (currItem.getItemName().toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
              mData.add(currItem);
          }
       }
   } else {
       // Adding all the items, if query is empty
       for (ModelItem item : tempData) {
           items.add(item);
       }
   }
   notifyDataSetChanged(); // notify the changes, if you are using an adapter.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a listview with items. Now you want to filter them with a search string.

You have to implement **Filterable** in your custom adapter.
[How to filter an adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14663821/6632568)

Answer (score 1):

hey i got a example for your requirement in github, you need to use QueryTextListener in main class, then setFilter to adapter as given in example
please check this link:https://github.com/Wrdlbrnft/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo