# Filtering Json Listview with edittext and custom adapter

Tags: android, json, filter, adapter

Trying to filter my Listview with a EditText, but everytime i enter text on my EditText my listview just goes blank, and returns no results. I've tried many approaches and this one seems like the most simple to implement. Any help would be much appreciated!

on my adapter:

```
public class AdapterTrilhos extends BaseAdapter {
private final Activity activity;

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Trilhos> triList;
private ArrayList<Trilhos> arraylist=null;


public AdapterTrilhos(List<Trilhos> triList, Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.triList = triList;
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Trilhos>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(triList);

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.triList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return this.triList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dadoslista, null);

            TextView idtxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtid);

            TextView tittxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txttit);

           // TextView usertxt = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtuser);

            TextView diftxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtdif);
   RatingBar ratess= (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratings);

            Trilhos t = triList.get(position);

            idtxt.setText(String.valueOf(t.getId()));
            tittxt.setText(t.getTitulo());
         //   usertxt.setText(String.valueOf(t.getId_user()));
            diftxt.setText(t.getDificuldade());
            ratess.setRating(t.getMedia());

        return convertView;
    }

public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    triList.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        triList.addAll(arraylist);
    } else {
        for (Trilhos cs : arraylist) {
            if (cs.getTitulo().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                triList.add(cs);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}
and on my activity

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int textlength = cs.length();

            String text = search.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            adapter.filter(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

what i plan to do, is when i enter text on my editText it will only return the results with the words i enter

Comment: attach complete adapter class.

Comment: Updated, should i post all my other activity?

Comment: try log your string value in filter method.

Comment: the string is getting there correctly, problem is data wont update, and just gives blank list

Comment: Have you try this Solutions [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android)? its work for me!

Comment: ive tried all solutions, always coming up with a empty list

Comment: @Asad everytime i enter text on my edittext the listview goes blank with no returns

Answer (score 2):

I think you should filter the list directly in your activity then swap to a new adapter :

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before, int count) {
        int textlength = cs.length();

        String text = search.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

        List<Trilhos> filteredList = yourFilterMethod(oldList, text); 

        mListView.setAdapter(new AdapterTrilhos(filteredList, this));

    }
});

private List<Trilhos> yourFilterMethod(List<object> list, String text)
{
    // some stuff that filter your list using text and returns the filtered one

    return filteredList;
}
```

Comment: should i keep the filter on my adapter?

Comment: @Sapo121 Which errors ? No you shouldn't because you would now filter the list in the activity, you move it to the activity and makes it return a new list instead of modifying it directly on your adapter

Comment: So basically, i need to create another adapter, filter my list and add the data to the new adapter i created?

Comment: @Sapo121 I edited my answer to use your class names. You should have ONE adapter that take cares of showing your data. And then in your activity a filter method that returns a filtered list that you then use on a new AdapterTrilhos that you set to your listView

Answer (score 1):

try this ?

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int textlength = cs.length();

        String text = cs.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        adapter.filter(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: same result, blank list.

Comment: man I am using the same code and its working perfectly for me. Need to debug a bit you are nearly there

Comment: yea, i know im almost there, it has to be something loading or reloading the list that im making some mistake

Comment: what u have on your filter class?