# android ListView duplicate items after filter

Tags: java, android, listview, filter, duplicates

after the list is filtered the filtered items are duplicated
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGUZq.png)

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Please post the filter method code

Comment: https://github.com/arsalanses/AndroidOnlineDictionary

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your filter(String) function, you don't add items 2 times to the array used by the listview

Maybe you've done something like that:

```
if (item.getName().contains(string)) {
    filter.add(item);
}

if (item.getDescription().contains(string)) {
    filter.add(item);
}
```

Comment: I dont use external function: https://github.com/arsalanses/AndroidOnlineDictionary

Comment: So you must add a custom filter
Here is another thread that might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/35489685/7292958