# How can I add a row from within the application ? Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, if-statement, tablelayout

hi guys i'm need your Help

I am doing a shopping app
The user will enter the barcode and the program will enter the name and price of the product

[Here is a picture of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTlMl.png)

But I don't know exactly how to do that.
I used the "TableLayout"
And I added 14 "tableRow"
and here is my code

```
code=findViewById(R.id.barcode);
code.addTextChangedListener(enter);
    }
    private TextWatcher enter = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if(code.getText().toString().trim().equals("659245631")) {
                //what can i write here to add row like this
                // (coulmn0,coulmn1)
                // ( price ,  product name)
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(code.getText().toString().trim().equals("659245631"))
            {


            }

        }
    };
```

But I do not know what is the required action Can you help me?

Comment: i'm really need help:(

Comment: You can replace `TableRow` with `ListView` or `RecycleView`, and filter it based on your barcode. [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-make-a-listview-in-android) is an simple example on how create a ListView [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android) is an example on how filter in listView.